# Multiple form validation with jQuery plugin submit by onclick without submit button

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have multiple form but it need to validation by jquery validation plugin. when i use submit button it works fine but when i use jquery on click function to submit form it works only first form and others form not working.

Here is my code.......

HTML...

```
<form class="validateForm">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
       <input id="form-field-9" class="form-control new_stock" name="new_stock" type="text">
    </div>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="btn btn-xs btn-green stock_details" title="Product Stock Update">
     <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
         Stock Update
     </a>
</form>
```

my jquery......

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var site_url = $('.site_url').val();
        var stockUpdateForm =  $('.validateForm').each(function(key, form) {
            $(form).validate({
                rules: {
                    new_stock: {
                        required: true,
                        digits:true
                    }
                },
                highlight: function (element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
                },
                unhighlight: function (element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
                },
                errorElement: 'span',
                errorClass: 'help-block',
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        $('.stock_details').on('click', function () {
           if(stockUpdateForm.valid()) {
               // only one form work but another form not working
           }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Note: when use submit button it works fine but not working click function

Comment: How is it supposed to know which form when your click handler is targeting them all at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code...

```
$('.stock_details').on('click', function () {
    if(stockUpdateForm.valid()) { ....
```

You can only attach the `.valid()` method to a specific form or form element, however your `stockUpdateForm` represents neither kind of thing.

Try this instead.  Using jQuery's `$(this)` keyword, you can target only the relevant `form` surrounding the clicked button.

```
$('.stock_details').on('click', function () {
    if($(this).parent('form').valid()) { ....
```